# Display dates based on week() result, except Sunday

Tags: mysql, date

So we all know that we can get the week number of a date by using the [week() function.](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php) My question is how to display the dates of that particular week, except the Sunday date?

To illustrate..

[image]

Based from the above example, what I want to display is..

- 2009-05-17
- 2009-05-18
- 2009-05-19
- 2009-05-20
- 2009-05-21
- 2009-05-22

How do I query this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @GivenDate ='2016-05-27';

SET @YearNum = YEAR(@GivenDate);
SET @WeekNum=WEEK(@GivenDate);

select selected_date,weekday(selected_date) AS WeeKDate
from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where YEAR(selected_date)=@YearNum
AND WEEK(selected_date)=@WeekNum
AND WEEKDAY(selected_date)<> 6;
```

Comment: This works, thank you. However when I try to set the date to `2016-05-27` , it starts from `2016-05-22`, which is a Sunday, to `2016-05-27`. It should be `2016-05-23` - `2016-05-28`.

Comment: Great. Glad I could help.